# Azure Data factory continous deployment using powershell

Tags: powershell, continuous-deployment, azure-data-factory

I need to do Continous Integration and Deployment for my Azure Data Factory (ADF).

For this in a Visual Studio solution I have two projects:

- one for ADF json files(linked services, datasets etc.).
- one for PowerShell script for deploying this ADF into a Azure subscription.

## Steps followed

Took MSBUILD of ADF codes and used copy files task to copy into `$(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)`.

Used Publish artifacts task to publish in VSTS.

Publish artifacts for PowerShell script as a separate build.

## Release

In my release I have a Azure PowerShell script which will invoke these ADF files and deploy it in Azure subscription. I'm using "Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory" for referring my ADF files. But I'm getting the below error -

> The term 'Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program

```
foreach($file in Get-ChildItem "$(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)" -filter "*LinkedService*")
{
    New-AzureRmDataFactoryLinkedService -ResourceGroupName "ADFAutomationResource" -DataFactoryName "ADFCICD190218" -Name $file.BaseName -File $file.FullName -Force | Format-List
}
```

Let me know how to proceed in this case..as there are no sufficient links explaining this.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
foreach($file in Get-ChildItem $Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory -filter "*LinkedService*")
{
    New-AzureRmDataFactoryLinkedService -ResourceGroupName "ADFAutomationResource" -DataFactoryName "ADFCICD190218" -Name $file.BaseName -File $file.FullName -Force | Format-List
}
```

Comment: Release got succedded, but it didn't get deployed in my subscription..will check and come back

Answer (score 0):

You're referencing a *Build* variable in a *Release*!

I assume you've added your artifacts to the release?

[image: Release artifacts]

If so; you should be able to refer to them like so:

```
$(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)/<Artifact Name>
```